# MySQL Semi synchronous replication stuck

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication

I have a mysql semi-synchronous replica-set with a master and 2 slaves. The replication happens fine to only one of the nodes but the other node is always stuck with the following status. Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event

Master does not send any data and I see the following in the master mysqld error logs.

```
2018-05-14T06:43:51.880292Z 113 [ERROR] Semi-sync master failed on
   net_flush() before waiting for slave reply
2018-05-14T06:43:51.880985Z 113 [Note] Stop semi-sync binlog_dump to slave (server_id: 111)
2018-05-14T06:44:41.754052Z 1343 [Note] While initializing dump thread 
   for slave with UUID <770ca92e-5730-11e8-9f7a-000d3a064af1>, found a
   zombie dump thread with the same UUID. Master is killing the zombie 
   dump thread(113).
2018-05-14T06:44:41.863759Z 1343 [Note] Start binlog_dump to 
   master_thread_id(1343) slave_server(111), pos(, 4)
2018-05-14T06:46:11.934785Z 1382 [Note] While initializing dump thread 
   for slave with UUID <770ca92e-5730-11e8-9f7a-000d3a064af1>, found a
   zombie dump thread with the same UUID. Master is killing the zombie 
   dump thread(113).
2018-05-14T06:46:11.934894Z 1382 [Note] Start binlog_dump to
    master_thread_id(1382) slave_server(111), pos(, 4)
2018-05-14T06:47:11.985863Z 1408 [Note] While initializing dump thread 
    for slave with UUID <770ca92e-5730-11e8-9f7a-000d3a064af1>, found a
    zombie dump thread with the same UUID. Master is killing the zombie 
    dump thread(113).
```

and so on....

my slave_net_timeout is 60 s on the slave and I can clearly see that after every 60 s the slave is trying to reconnect, but the master acknowledges and holds the connection but does not send any data. As a side effect, the number of slave connections to master continuously grows. I also see the following in Show Processlist for the master:

```
|  113 | repl_user | 172.19.0.12:58174 | NULL | Binlog Dump GTID | 3189 | Waiting to finalize termination | NULL
| 1343 | repl_user | 172.19.0.12:35394 | NULL | Binlog Dump GTID | 418 | starting | NULL |
| 1382 | repl_user | 172.19.0.12:35572 | NULL | Binlog Dump GTID | 328 | starting | NULL |
```

Any pointers and to debug this further will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What version(s) of MySQL are you using? - https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=77195

Comment: I am using 5.7.21

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50678183/1695906).